# SDL_PollEvent does not work

Tags: c++, event-handling, sdl

I'm doing this tutorial about SDL in game development. The program should leave the main loop when finding an input, but it does not:

```
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gXOut = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (!init()){
        printf("Failed to initialize.\n");
    }
    else {
        //Load media
        if (!loadMedia()){
            printf("Failed to load media.\n");
        }
        else {
            //Main loop flag
            bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //While application is runnig
            while (!quit){
                //Handles events on queue
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0){
                    //User requests quit
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }

                //Aply the image
                SDL_BlitSurface(gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);

                //Update the surface
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);

            }
        }
    }

    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
```

I've tried changing SDL_QUIT for SDL_KEYPRESSED but it doesn't work either. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

SDL_KEYPRESSED does not exist in SDL2. If you want to quit the program using a keyboard input, use SDL_KEYDOWN or SDL_KEYUP in the loop like this :

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0){

    if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){  // or SDL_KEYUP
       quit = true;
    }
```

Please take a look on the [wiki page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_KeyboardEvent).

Comment: I misspelled it, I meant KEYDOWN, which didn't work either. Now it is solved. But then my question is, what does exactly handle SDL_QUIT?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code looks for what you are trying to achieve:

```
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;



int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    //Main loop flag
    bool quit = false;

    //Event handler
    SDL_Event e;

    SDL_Surface* gXOut = NULL;

    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n",                 SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n",         SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay(2000);
        }
    }

        //While application is running
        while (!quit)
        {
                //Handle events on queue
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) //can change the SD_QUIT event to whatever you want to customize with.
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }
                //Apply the image
                SDL_BlitSurface(gXOut, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

The SDL_QUIT takes the input when the X on the window is pressed, or change the key to something else if you want to quit with a different key in your application.